# C# Stripe no paymnetIntentId Provided

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, payment

Good day,
I am using Stripe as a payment getaway,

```
            var service = new SessionService();
            Session session = service.Create(options);
```

I know that Stripe changed its API and now
when you use Stripe Checkout, you won't have a PaymentIntent, but will have a CheckoutSession instead. How do I call ChekcoutSession to get paymentIntentID?

Comment: what's the api version you are using?

Comment: I am using MVC dotnet 6, and stripe 41.13.0 package

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as of API version [2022-08-01](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-08-01) a Payment Intent is no longer generated on creation of a Checkout Session. Instead, we [defer](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-08-01:%7E:text=A%20PaymentIntent%20is%20no%20longer%20created%20during%20Checkout%20Session%20creation%20in%20payment%20mode.%20Instead%2C%20a%20PaymentIntent%20will%20be%20created%20when%20the%20Session%20is%20confirmed.) the creation of the Payment Intent to confirmation (payment) of the session.

Due to that change, the API response to your Checkout Session creation call will have a `payment_intent: null` [field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/versioning) if either:

- The default API version on your account is 2022-08-01 (or newer).
- You pass the 2022-08-01 version (or newer) when making your API request, via the `apiVersion` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/versioning).

Comment: Why do you need a Payment Intent returned on session creation?

Comment: For refunds, it asks paymentIntentId or charge

Comment: So how do I get paymentIntent?

Comment: On session creation thought there is not payment to refund. My recommendation would be to instead listen to the `checkout.session.completed` [event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed), which will fire once your customer completes the session/payment and will contain a `payment_intent: 'pi_xxx'`. This can then be used in any subsequent refunds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I really have no idea how to listen for an event for checkout.session.completed. Could you write a short example on how to do it?

Comment: I'd recommend reading the guides on both webhooks [here](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks), and specific to Checkout fulfilment [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders). Alternatively you could revert your API version back to version that pre-dates the change.